# Why B b = new A() is invalid and A a = new B() is valid when B extends A?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am new to JAVA and want to know that why

```
A a = new B();
```

is valid
and

```
B b = new A();
```

is invalid
Considering that:

```
class A;
class B extends A;
```

Comment: Every apple is a fruit, is every fruit an apple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `B`, by extending `A`, is also an `A`.  We say this in object-orientation terms by saying that a `B` **is-a** `A`.  This means that you can use a `B` anywhere you use an `A`.

This relationship is not commutative -- `B` is-a `A` does *not* imply that `A` is-a `B`.  Therefore you cannot use an `A` anywhere you would use a `B`.

Consider this case:

```
class Animal;
class Dog extends Animal;
```

This makes sense:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
```

Anywhere it makes sense to use an `Animal` you can also use a `Dog`.  This is intuitive.

```
Dog dog = new Animal();
```

This, on the other hand, does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because when B extends A you consider that every B is a more complex A, using the attributes and methods from A and adding some of his own, but an A cannot be a B, there could be methods in B not specified in A, and as it is not extended from B, cannot be instantiated.

Every B is an A , but no every A is a B ( unless you specify that )

Answer (score -1):

```
class A { 
   int i = 10;
}

class B {
   int i = 10;
   int j = 20;
}

class C {

   public static void main(String args[]){   
      B b;
      B b=new A();
      System.out.println(b.j);
   }
}
```

Comment: In java,a base class-reference can refer to an object of derived class but   a derived class-reference can not refer to an object of base class. Now, in the above example, a B type refence b is referring to an object of class A and trying to access and print the value of member j of that object.But, as this object is of class A,it does not have any member called j. As a non-existent member of the object(of class A) is being tried to be accessed,the program will show error.

Comment: That's totally irrelevant answer. In java syntax is like this: `Class object = new Class();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This answer does not make sense. `B b=new A();` will not compile unless `A extends B`, but it does not.